nx - Using Angular 17 but not vite. How do i enable vite
I have the latest NX and the latest angular but my app is not using vite yet. I see hints of how to opt in online but none of the instructions make sense cause i dont have an angular.json in my project. Instead my nx project has individual project.json files for libs and apps .
How do i opt in to vite?
Node   : 18.13.0
OS     : darwin-arm64
npm    : 8.19.3

nx                 : 18.2.4
@nx/js             : 18.2.4
@nx/jest           : 18.2.4
@nx/linter         : 18.2.4
@nx/eslint         : 18.2.4
@nx/workspace      : 18.2.4
@nx/angular        : 18.2.4
@nx/cypress        : 18.2.4
@nx/devkit         : 18.2.4
@nx/eslint-plugin  : 18.2.4
@nx/express        : 18.2.4
@nx/node           : 18.2.4
@nx/storybook      : 18.2.4
@nrwl/tao          : 18.2.4
@nx/web            : 18.2.4
@nx/webpack        : 18.2.4
nx-cloud           : 18.0.0
typescript         : 5.4.5
---------------------------------------
Community plugins:
@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome : 0.9.0
@ngneat/tailwind                 : 7.0.3
@scullyio/init                   : 2.1.41
@storybook/angular               : 7.6.17
rxjs                             : 6.6.7

Angular: 17.3.3
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, pwa, router
... service-worker, ssr

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.3
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.3
@angular/fire                   7.6.1
@angular/google-maps            13.3.9
@schematics/angular             17.3.3
ng-packagr                      17.3.0
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      5.4.5
zone.js                         0.14.4


Generate an NX library and choose vitest as a test runner. Then, update and copy the generated vite configuration into the desired project root. After that, go to project.json configuration file and update the test executer property.

I will try this. Is there a generator for this?

 npx nx g @nx/js:lib --help
